# How do I activate SSL for my AppEngine with java application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, ssl

Please let me know the process to configure my custom domain (http://www.myapp.in) with SSL. If i do follow the below process, Does it guaranteed to be secure my application? As i know that the process Google gives us...
    "https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl" in this doc, i found the process is below to **Activating** heading.

And also please let me know that "Is it free of cost?"

Any reply can welcome,
Thanks in advance.

Satyarao

Answer (score 0):

1. Theres nothing special about java here. Enabling SSL is always the same on GAE, regardless of the language used.
2. SSL on https://appid.appspot.com is always available and free of charge.
3. SSL on custom domains costs money. The connection itself is secure (if you use a valid certificate and keep this secret). However its up to your application to enforce the usage of SSL, and doing the whole other security related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's free to enable. Add the `secure:always` line in your configuration file (app.yaml): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Secure_URLs